# Not able to receive ajax post data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to print a calendar using php but struggle figuring out how to change the month displayed with ajax

I have two buttons in  tag whose value is "+1" and "-1" respectively with a class="selectMonth"

```
<button class="selectMonth" name="selectMonth" value="-1">previous</button>
<button class="selectMonth" name="selectMonth" value="+1">next</button>
```

This is my ajax code:

```
$(".selectMonth").on("click", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : "index.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : {selectMonth : this.value},
            success : function(){
                alert("success!");
            }

        });

    });
```

and in my index.php I have

```
    <?php 
if(!isset($_POST["selectMonth"]))
    $_SESSION["date"] = time();
else
{
    $selectMonth = $_POST["selectMonth"];
    $_SESSION["date"] = strtotime($selectMonth . 'month');
}
var_dump($_POST["selectMonth"]);

$date = $_SESSION["date"];
print_calendar($date);

?>
```

After I click one of the buttons, I can get the alert message but not the $_POST variable and what is var_dump is always NULL

Could anybody find out the mistake for me?
I'm still learning ajax.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".selectMonth").on("click", function(){
    var inputVal = $(this).attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        url : "index.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : {selectMonth : inputVal},
        success : function(){
            alert("success!");
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Your buttons HTML please?

Comment: Are you using any kind of frameworks which unset the global $_POST?

Comment: <button class="selectMonth" name="selectMonth" value="-1">previous</button>

Comment: Ok.. use var inputVal = $(this).attr ('value');

Answer (score 1):

try below line of code :

```
data : {'selectMonth' : $(this).val()},
```

OR

```
data : {'selectMonth' : $(this).attr('value')},
```

Comment: I believe this does the same as this.value

Comment: and I'm still getting NULL

Comment: Also check my updated ans and try with that if helpful to you

Comment: Actually that is all my html code, the print_calendar function is just to print a calendar.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with getting the value of the button using this.value, cuz when i alert(this.value) i can receive +1 or -1

Comment: one more thing, how did you check posted values? From console or else?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
data : {selectMonth : this.value}
```

try

```
data : {selectMonth : this.val()}
```

Comment: I believe this may throw an exception saying that `this` have no function `val()`. Maybe this works `$(this).val()`.

Comment: It doesn't even alert the success message then.

Comment: hey DontVoteMeDown, i get the success message but still getting NULL